# How conditionally format text color for an entire row based on the value of a separate field in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-formatting, textcolor

I have an SSRS report and I want to dynamically change the text color for the "entire row" based on the value of the year field. So for instance if the fiscal year is current, make the text green and otherwise black. I found solution to conditionally update the background color for the row and I understand that using textbox properties I can achieve this for one single cell. The problem is that my reports are massive. Is there any way to apply the condition to the entire row or segment of the tablix without the need to copy the condition hundreds of times?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just select the row header on the left of the tablix, hit F4 to get the properties panel visible, and set the 'Color' property expression.

[image]

What this actually does is set the `Color' property of all the selected cells/textboxes and, by clicking the row header, you have selected all the cells on that row. This means that you can still change individual cells if required.

In short, the Row does not have a `Color` property of it's own but by selecting the row we can set the entire row in one step.

Additionally, if you want to select a bunch of rows, or cells, you can do this by Ctrl+Left Clicking (or dragging round cells in the same scope) and then setting the properties en masse.

All the above work for most properties such as size, format etc.